# The fixed space of a reprensentation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Given a characteristic $0$ representation of a finite group $G \to \text{GL}(V)$. We know that this induces an action of $G$ on $V$. Denote by $F(g) = \{v \in V| gv = v\}$, the fixed space of $g$. Assume that for each $g$, $\dim(F(g)) \geq \frac{1}{2}\dim V$, show that there exists $v \in V$ that is fixed by every $g \in G$.

Trying to use something like Burnside's lemma or class formula but $V$is clearly not finite thus those do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

$G=\{g_1,\cdots , g_k\}$ so
you can apply the Grassman formula to have that

$dim(V)\geq dim(F(g_1)+\cdots +F(g_k))=$

$\sum_{s=1}^k dim(F(g_s))-dim(\cap_{s=1}^kF(g_s))\geq$

$ \frac{k}{2}dim(V)-dim(\cap_{s=1}^kF(g_s) )$

So

$dim(\cap_{s=1}^kF(g_s))\geq (\frac{k}{2}-1)dim(V)>1$

when the order of $G$ is at least $3$

Comment: Why does it have to be a characteristic zero representation?

Comment: I don’t know and I think that Grassmann formula is not true for more of two subspaces